# Mapping an array in inside another array and display into a table in more than one entry

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, api

I have data that include the result of student each in an array but also with different subject basing on subject that they undertake. I want to map through them to be able to insert it into a table with respect to the subject and they mark which has to be matching.

This is my API result

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Successfully retrieve",
    "data": [
        {
            "studentNumber": "22001",
            "gender": "M",
            "result": [
                {
                    "moduleCode": "CHE1163",
                    "continousAssesment": 42,
                    "Exam": 6,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 55,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 38.18181818181819,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 44.18181818181819,
                    "studentNumber": "22001",
                    "moduleCredit": 10
                },
                {
                    "moduleCode": "MEE1162",
                    "continousAssesment": 10,
                    "Exam": 40,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 45,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 11.11111111111111,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 51.111111111111114,
                    "studentNumber": "22001",
                    "moduleCredit": 15
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "studentNumber": "1111",
            "gender": "M",
            "result": [
                {
                    "moduleCode": "CHE1163",
                    "continousAssesment": 0,
                    "Exam": 23,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 0,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 0,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 23,
                    "studentNumber": "1111",
                    "moduleCredit": 10
                },
                {
                    "moduleCode": "MEE1162",
                    "continousAssesment": 12,
                    "Exam": 20,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 45,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 13.333333333333334,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 33.333333333333336,
                    "studentNumber": "1111",
                    "moduleCredit": 15
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "studentNumber": "667",
            "gender": "F",
            "result": [
                {
                    "moduleCode": "CHE1163",
                    "continousAssesment": 0,
                    "Exam": 3,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 0,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 0,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 3,
                    "studentNumber": "667",
                    "moduleCredit": 10
                },
                {
                    "moduleCode": "MEE1162",
                    "continousAssesment": 17,
                    "Exam": 40,
                    "workMaxContinousAssement": 45,
                    "actualContinousAssesment": 18.88888888888889,
                    "actualMaxContinousAssesment": 50,
                    "maxExam": 50,
                    "total": 58.888888888888886,
                    "studentNumber": "667",
                    "moduleCredit": 15
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the result I should be expecting is something like this

[image: picture of the outcome]

I have tried to map from to but it showing nothing when I replace the value as variable

this is the part of the table code

```html
overallResult.map((item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>{item.studentNumber}</td>
          <td className="font-medium">{item.gender}</td>
          <td>44.18181818181819</td>
          <td>51.111111111111114</td>
          <td>45</td>
       </tr>
      </>
  )
}
```

This should be mapping and then insert the actual value into the  for the map which is corresponding to the student as seen in table picture

Comment: What is overallResult?

Comment: What is the output of the console.log? 
But basically you should loop through the array with the name whatever you call it  like `arr.data.map`

Comment: overallResult is the object that contains the data from the api

Comment: then it should be `overallResult.data.map()`

Comment: The how could I loop through the result (total) and display it in the table with respect to both the module code and the studentNumber

Comment: if you could put your code in codesandbox, i could help you better. https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-knuth-y8gj0m

Comment: I have inserted the code in the sandbox give you can check them out, but I haven't done any mapping or looping it a raw table that I have insert

to explain it on the header we should map the moduleCode that the student undertakes, then on the left side we map the studentNumber, then below the moduleCodes we map there marks with respect to the moduleCode and StudentNumber

Comment: @ Cooling Nziza can't see updated sandbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249991/discussion-between-cooling-nziza-and-greg).

Comment: am sorry I didn't notice that it had to fork it to be able to save this the changes.
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-elion-ut36zs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey @Cooling Nziza give me some time, I am fixing your code

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bardeen-brkzf5?file=/src/App.js). 
Instead of hard coded data, now your table is populated with the data from `overallResult` object.
It is not perfect, but at least you can see how to loop through a data and display on the screen.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bardeen-brkzf5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can see that is looping the whole table but how could I loop every thing within one table

Comment: hey, i updated the sandbox link. I left some work for you, but you should get the point